# Ahora todo el tiempo que imprimo me sale el texto con mas contraste¿como lo soluciono?

Tags: java, consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy aprendiendo sobre estos comandos para pintar secuencias de caracteres y una vez que pinto una String como ven , al aplicar la variableANSI_RESET no vuelve a su estado original.

Ademas de que el atributo del color que sea se puede pasar hasta otro System.out.println();

Talvez no se note pero le subi el contraste al texto y ya no puedo bajarlo, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido , revisa [ask]. Como subiste el contraste al texto?

Comment: Solo puse este codigo  "\u001B[1m"

Comment: [como usar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)